# Integrals involving Gamma Functions

Tags: laplace-transform, contour-integration, gamma-function, beta-function

How can we compute the following integrals:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \; \frac{\Gamma(l + ix) \,\Gamma(l - ix)}{\Gamma(2l)} \,\exp((a+ it)x) = \int_\infty^\infty dx \, \text{B}(l + ix, l-ix) \exp((a + it)x),  \;\; \text{for}  \; \;0< a < \pi,\, l > 0,\; t \in \mathbb{R} \, \text{and},$

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, dy\; \frac{\Gamma(l + ix) \,\Gamma(l + iy)\, \Gamma(-ix-iy)}{\Gamma(2l)} \exp((a+ it)x + (b + it') y )\;\; \text{for} \;\; 0<a,b < \pi, \,l> 0, \; t,t' \in \mathbb{R} $

Are these integrals standard? If so, please suggest some sources.